# Getting data from 4 joined tables in on query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

[image: database tables]
.

I have 4 tables as shown above. Now I'm trying to get all the data including article subjects, tags for each article, and number of comments for each article, in **ONE** query.

The sql query I'm using now is

```
SELECT
    articles.subject, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS tags, COUNT(comments.aid) AS comments
FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.aid = articles.aid
    LEFT JOIN relations ON relations.aid = articles.aid
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tid = relations.tid
GROUP BY
    articles.aid
```

The result: **data in [ ] is what I actually get**

```
array
(
    1 => array
    (
        subject => foo
        tags =>
        comments => 1
    )
    2 => array
    (
        subject => bar
        tags => html,mysql [html,mysql,html,mysql]
        comments => 2 [4]
    )
    3 => array
    (
        subject => baz
        tags => php
        comments => 0
    )
)
```

For the real situation here in my application, number of tags and number of comments will multiply with each other. For example: if there are 4 comments, and 3 tags in one article, my query will result in

tags: html,css,php, html,css,php, html,css,php, html,css,php (instead of html,css,php)

comments: 12 (instead of 4)

I know there must be something wrong with my query statement, I just don't know how to fix it.
Someone please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a nested query to count the comments

```
SELECT
    articles.subject, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) AS tags, comments
FROM articles
    LEFT JOIN (
          select aid,count(cid) as comments from comments group by aid
    ) AS commentscount ON commentscount.aid = articles.aid
    LEFT JOIN relations ON relations.aid = articles.aid
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tid = relations.tid
GROUP BY
    articles.aid
```

Answer (score 1):

When you join tables together on common columns, you get *all combinations* of rows that share those columns.

In this case, for `aid 2`, there is 1 row from articles, 2 from comments, and 2 from relations. 1*2*2 = 4, which is what you are seeing as the result of the `COUNT()` function.

If you were to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.aid = articles.aid
LEFT JOIN relations ON relations.aid = articles.aid
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tid = relations.tid
WHERE articles.aid = 2
```

You would be able to see the four generated rows that `COUNT` is counting.

```
aid | subject | cid | comment  | tid | name
----+---------+-----+----------+-----+------
2   | bar     | 1   | comment1 | 1   | html
2   | bar     | 1   | comment1 | 3   | mysql
2   | bar     | 2   | comment2 | 1   | html
2   | bar     | 2   | comment2 | 3   | mysql
```

If you want just want to count the number of comments, you can change the `COUNT(comments.aid)` in your query to `COUNT(DISTINCT comments.cid)` -- that will cast out the duplicates when it does the count.

Comment: Ian, thank you for the explanation. I did try the DISTINCT, it corrects the number of comments, but tags are still get duplicated. I think in my case it needs more work like guido suggested. But I'll keep your words in mind in case I run into similar problems in the future.

Comment: The tags are duplicated for the same reason. A quick fix is to use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name)`, but there are probably more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: By adding DISTINCT has corrected all the duplicates, both comment numbers and tags, and other fields in my real application. Also, it seems more obvious and easier to me (learner). You have mentioned efficiency, which I'm not quite sure which way of yours and guido's will do better.